# How to return a 3D array from C to Java?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, android-ndk, java-native-interface

let me present my situation:

PROBLEM: create a 3D array in c and pass it to java through JNI.

PROGRESS: I've tried many options so far, this is what I came to till now:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stddef.h>
#include<com_example_c2java_MainActivity.h>

JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_com_example_c2java_MainActivity_getArray
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
    double a[2][2][2];
    int i,j,k;
    double x = 0;
    jclass doubleClass = (*env)->FindClass(env,"Java/lang/Double");//
    jobjectArray ret  = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 2, doubleClass, NULL);


    for( i = 0; i<2; i++){
            for( j = 0; j<2; j++){
                    for( k = 0; k<2; k++){
                        x+=1;
                        a[i][j][k] = x;
                    }
            }
    }

    for( i = 0; i<2; i++){
                jdoubleArray tmp1 = (*env)->NewDoubleArray(env,2);;

                jdoubleArray dim2 = (*env)->NewDoubleArray(env,2);
                for( j = 0; j<2; j++){
                    jdouble tmp2[256];
                    jdoubleArray dim3 = (*env)->NewDoubleArray(env,2);

                    for( k = 0; k<2; k++){

                                            tmp2[k] = a[i][j][k];
                                        }
                    (*env)->SetDoubleArrayRegion(env,tmp1 , j, 2, tmp2);

                }
                (*env)->SetDoubleArrayRegion(env,dim2, 0, 2, tmp1);
                (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,ret, i, dim2);
                (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, dim2);
        }

    return ret;


}
```

java side:

```
package com.example.c2java;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        double[][][] arr = getArray();
        Log.i("ffff","-----------------------------"+arr[0][0][0]);
    }
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("C2Java");
    }
    public native double[][][] getArray();
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

BUG: Launching the app gives the following logcat error:

```
02-19 16:20:29.084: E/dalvikvm(20707): VM aborting
02-19 16:20:29.084: A/libc(20707): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 20707 (.example.c2java)
```

SOLUTION: your help is needed to find it :)

Comment: What do you have on the Java side?

Comment: @user1803551 I added the java code. any help?

Comment: "*any help?*" Yes, it does help. I needed to see `public native double[][][] getArray();` and where it is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood what the types involved are.

First of all, `Java/lang/Double` is not the same as the primitive type `double`. Secondly, `ret` should not be an array of `double`s, it should be an array of arrays of arrays of `double`s.

What you want to do is something like this:

```
jclass doubleArrayArrayClass = env->FindClass("[[D");
jclass doubleArrayClass = env->FindClass("[D");

// Create an array of arrays of arrays of double
jobjectArray ret  = env->NewObjectArray(2, doubleArrayArrayClass, NULL);

for( i = 0; i<2; i++){
    for( j = 0; j<2; j++){
        for( k = 0; k<2; k++){
            x+=1;
            a[i][j][k] = x;
        }
    }
}

for( i = 0; i<2; i++){
    // ret[i] is an array of arrays of double
    jobjectArray dim2 = env->NewObjectArray(2, doubleArrayClass, NULL);
    for( j = 0; j<2; j++) {
        // ret[i][j] is an array of double
        jdoubleArray dim1 = env->NewDoubleArray(2);
        jdouble tmp[256];
        for( k = 0; k<2; k++){
            tmp[k] = a[i][j][k];
        }
        env->SetDoubleArrayRegion(dim1 , 0, 2, tmp);
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(dim2, j, dim1);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(dim1);
    }
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(ret, i, dim2);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(dim2);
}
```

(I'm using C++-syntax for the JNI calls, so you'll have to change that back to C-syntax if you must use a C compiler)

Comment: I used your code(with C-syntax), no luck still the same error.

Comment: It works fine for me. If I print out `arr[0][0][0]` in the java code I get `1.0`.